# Change merge strategy from 'ort' to 'recursive'

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, merge-strategy

I don't know how, but default merge strategy is `ort` in my pc, but I want to change that to `recursive`. I referred some online sources but none of them were useful. Can someone tell me how can I change my default merge strategy?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can't:<sup>1</sup> the *default* merge strategy for `git merge`, `git cherry-pick`, etc., is hard-coded.<sup>2</sup>  You *can* easily run `git merge -s recursive`, either manually or through an alias.

The `-s recursive` and `-s ort` strategies are *supposed* to produce the same result except when `-s recursive` would bail out but `-s ort` can succeed.  If you come across cases where this isn't true, report them to the Git developers.

---

<sup>1</sup>For some definition of "can't" anyway: if you work hard enough at it, you certainly could.  For instance, just clone Git and customize it.

<sup>2</sup>For `git merge` in particular, the default is `octopus` when giving multiple heads, and otherwise is whichever of `ort` or `recursive` it is for your particular Git version.

Comment: It is not true that you can't change it; [`pull.twohead`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pulltwohead) is respected by [`git merge`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a38d39a4c50d1275833aba54c4dbdfce9e2e9ca1/builtin/merge.c#L634-L635) and the [sequencer code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a38d39a4c50d1275833aba54c4dbdfce9e2e9ca1/sequencer.c#L249-L261) used by `revert`, `cherry-pick` and `rebase`.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR;
set environment variable `GIT_TEST_MERGE_ALGORITHM=recursive`

Found out in the [source code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/815c1e82021edbd99a2c423cf27f28863f28cef3/builtin/merge.c#L167) of git it check first for environment variable `GIT_TEST_MERGE_ALGORITHM`

once setting the value to `recursive` it change the default merge strategy.
I don't think it's the cleanest solution because of the `TEST` in the environment variable (probably meant for testing) but it's better then nothing.

Comment: Ugh, do NOT use GIT_TEST_MERGE_ALGORITHM.  It could be ripped out at any time in future git releases.  pull.twohead (as mentioned in a comment by philb above) is the user configuration option you can tweak to pick a different merge algorithm.