# Exclude a file from merging to the main branch

Tags: git, jenkins, merge, bitbucket, gitattributes

### The environment:

We use Bitbucket Cloud for repository management (and merges) and Jenkins for CI/CD.  Branches with open pull requests are built and deployed to a temporary environment (which includes a taking snapshot of the DB schema and data as currently deployed) where integration tests are performed. The main branch is treated similarly, except that it is also deployed to a "permanent" environment for QA, etc. This is done automatically using Jenkins scripts.

Merges to the main branch are performed by the developers in the Bitbucket UI after the PR has the necessary approvals and the build/deploy process above passes.

### The problem:

Some PRs require changes both in the code and the DB. The integration tests will fail if the DB schema differs from what the code expects or if crucial data is missing.

### The approach:

We would like to use change-specific SQL scripts that would apply the required DB changes in the temporary build environments onto the DB snapshot before the integration tests are run.

A convenient approach would be to have a stub `db_changes.sql` file in the repository that the developers can modify in the feature/bugfix branches, which will be picked up by the build/deployment scripts together with the rest of the branch, but exclude it from merging to the main branch.  That will ensure that branching off of the main branch will result in an empty `db_changes.sql` file and no DB changes will be attempted when the code does not require them.

### The issue:

The obvious way of using [git attributes to specify a merge strategy](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_merge_strategies) for that file [does not work on Bitbucket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78075587/181238).

### Brainstorming alternatives:

One idea is to [change the default merge option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73701272/change-merge-strategy-from-ort-to-recursive#comment132527075_73711712) (if it is possible on Bitbucket) to `recursive`, which would ostensibly allow the use of git attributes for merge strategies. However, it appears that `recursive` can be [noticeably slower](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-13011?focusedId=2889390&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-2889390) than `ort`.

Another option is to use a separate DB changes script for each branch, with a naming convention that will associate the file name with the branch name, but this seems fragile and prone to typos.

### Edit: Constraints and limitations

Unfortunately we are just a small team in a large company, and don't have the luxury of choosing "better" tools, so we are trying to make the best of what we are given to work with: Bitbucket Cloud (migration to Github is planned) and Jenkins.

Please advise.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you would like to solve this using Git? The way you're aiming to use sounds overcomplicated, as well as reinventing the wheel in some sense. A common approach nowadays would be usage of a specialized database migration tool such as Liquibase or Flyway, and a containerized database with something like TestContainers (or at least with some automation that allows to lock either the resources of a standalone database or one of several standalone l DB instances).

Comment: Mostly because we don't operate in a vacuum and don't own the DB. Convincing the rest of the company to adopt to the "right" tools is not feasible at this point so we need to make the best of what we have.

Comment: No one operates in a vacuum :) I don't want to disappoint you but it's really a dead-end. At some point it would be considered legacy and then rewritten anyways, but at the cost of much more efforts. You don't have to convince anyone - you already have access to your source code (thus to your build tool configuration and Jenkinsfile) and it could be enough. If you could specify your application tech stack the answers to your question would be more targeted.

Comment: As a small team, you don't have the luxury of throwing time and effort at a problem. You need to be efficient which means good tools. If your team has enough control over your build process to set up hooks and introduce database change files, you have enough control to change how you test your code. Nothing suggested so far requires moving away from Bitbucket nor Jenkins.

Comment: Could you give some examples of what would be in this hypothetical db_changes.sql file?

Comment: Regarding: "The integration tests will fail if the DB schema differs from what the code expects or if crucial data is missing." Why is that only true on the test Env? Don't you need the same DB schema and/or DB data changes to be made to Prod as well?

Comment: As far as managing your database schéma and its versions, there are so many ways to choose from. Choosing one that which depends on a particular file in your repository to be empty, and trying to use git as an active component in its process, seems odd at best. Do take time to review your db deployment process, and look if you can choose a way to manage this with code alone, and possibly with parameters that are not versioned in git.

Answer (score 1):

> A convenient approach would be to have a stub db_changes.sql file in the repository that the developers can modify in the feature/bugfix branches, which will be picked up by the build/deployment scripts together with the rest of the branch, but exclude it from merging to the main branch. That will ensure that branching off of the main branch will result in an empty db_changes.sql file and no DB changes will be attempted when the code does not require them.

You could probably accomplish this with [hooks](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/how-tos/register-maintain-hook-scripts/). You'd merge PRs into a special branch, let's call it special_merge. Your hook would see the merge on special_merge, add a commit to empty the special `db_changes.sql` file, and merge that into main. The [PostRepositoryHook](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/how-tos/hooks-merge-checks-guide/) would seem to do it.

```
A - B - C [main][special_merge]
 \
  X - Y - Z [branch]

# merge the PR to special_merge

A - B --- C [main]
 \         \
  \         M [special_merge]
   \        /
   X - Y - Z [branch]

# hook detects a merge to special_merge.
# checks out the branch head.
# empties db_changes.sql
# commits (that's commit 0)

A - B --- C [main]
 \         \
  \         M [special_merge]
   \        /
   X - Y - Z - 0 [branch]

# hook merges branch into main
# hook resets special_merge to main

A - B --- C ------ N [main][special_merge]
 \                /
  \              /
   \            /
   X - Y - Z - 0 [branch]
```

There's a bunch of problems with this approach.

1. It complicates the merge process.
2. How are changes to the database schema handled? Where is it stored? How is it tested?
3. What if a change needs to modify production data? Where is it stored? How is it tested?
4. What you're testing is not what you're pushing to production.

---

There are two problems.

1. Your database changes are not under version control and (presumably) are deployed using a different process than your code.
2. You're relying on a fixed database to test diverse code.

If we fix both problems the problem goes away, deployments and testing are more robust, and the whole deployment pipeline can be automated.

What you're describing is on the way to [schema migrations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration). Rather than having a fixed schema you temporarily modify, *every* change to the database is done this way. The schema is generated by running each change on an empty database. You can then dump a snapshot of your schema.

For example, your first schema migration would create the database as it currently exists. In development and testing, this is used to generate a schema and create the database (and normally would be used to create the initial production database). This database has no data, except a table for tracking which migrations have already been applied.

Tests always start with no data. Developers writing tests use tools such as [factory_bot](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/) to generate test data and populate the database. The database is emptied between tests, at as fine a grain as possible, usually by rolling back a transaction. This avoids a failing test from messing up the database, each test starts from a known clean state.

If a developer wants to make a change to the schema, they write a new schema migration. For example, a branch might include a schema migration with an `alter table` to add a new column. As before, all migrations are run in order to create the database for dev and testing.

Deploying this change in production means running the unapplied schema migrations in order first on a staging database which does have sample data similar to production (this could be a production snapshot, but be careful of exposing [PII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_data) to your devs and testers). Once its known to work on staging, the new migrations are then applied to production.

In this way dev, test, and production schemas can be tested and kept in sync automatically. Tests won't accidentally leave data to confuse other tests. Tests can insert and delete any data they want. Branches can make any changes to the database as necessary. Sensitive production data doesn't accidentally leak into dev and testing.

- dev - developers creates fresh, empty databases to develop and work on using test factories to populate them with data
- testing - same as dev
- staging - staging has an existing database with production-like data and only applies new schema migrations, this tests production deployment
- production - same as staging

Testing confirms the code and schema will work before merging. Staging confirms the schema changes will work with a live database before deploying.

Many ORMs and frameworks support this workflow out of the box, and there are stand-alone tools such as [Sqitch](https://sqitch.org/).

Comment: While I agree about using the right tool for the job, unfortunately we don't operate in a vacuum and don't own the DB. Convincing the rest of the company to adopt to the "right" tools is not feasible at this point so we need to make the best of what we have. As for hooks: I checked and could not find server-side hooks for merge.

Comment: @AlexO Not owning the DB makes it simpler, you don't have to do schema migrations; just copy their schema. The major thing is rather than testing against a fixed set of data (a test fixture), your tests generate data as needed. You can do this progressively, writing new tests with test factories, rewriting old tests to use test factories instead of the fixture. You shouldn't have to convince the rest of the company, just your team working on this code, unless you're working on some massive monolith project?

Comment: @AlexO  As to the hooks, [PostRepositoryHook](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/how-tos/hooks-merge-checks-guide/) looks like what you want.

Comment: I do not think that PostRepositoryHook is available on [Bitbucket Cloud](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Are-PostRepositoryHooks-still-available/qaq-p/2460959)

Comment: @AlexO How about a [webhook](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/event-payloads/) on the Merged event?